# Couldn't start the machine due to Network Adapter not found. Can't click okay to save settings

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I know this question has been answered many times before but my issue seems to be unique as all the solutions that have worked for many people do not seem to work for me. When I try and start Ubuntu in Virtual Box it comes up with the same [error many people have been reporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgmk1.png)

One of the solutions to this I did find was to make sure the MAC Address was the same as the one on the host OS. I changed it to the host OS and had an issue a lot of other people have been reporting as well, I couldn't click okay to save the settings. The main solution to this seemed to be solving the "Invalid setting detected" at the bottom before being able to click okay.

Mine (as with most people's issues) was needing to [disable the hardware virtualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZbc9.png). I tried this as well and was still not able to save the settings, and this is where I need help. Even with trying to solve both of these issues it still says I need to disable the hardware virtualization and so I cannot click okay to save the settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as having Linux on my Windows PC would greatly help me with my fourth-year project in Uni, thank you in advance.

[Network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2PJP.png)
[Network Settings in vbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBGTI.png)

Comment: You have to shutdown the Ubuntu guest OS to change and save the network controller setting.

Comment: If by that you mean close the OS first and then go to the settings in Oracle VM for the guest OS then that's what I've been doing, I still get the same problem

Comment: Are you wishing to use the system's ethernet interface, or wireless interface? Is your wireless adapter a USB dongle? In settings, show me a screenshot of the network settings.

Comment: It's ethernet, I can still send a screenshot of the settings if it helps though

Comment: Your first image shows wireless. Yes, please show me a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: I added both the windows and vbox settings to the original post, if there's anything else you need just give me shout!

Comment: Update: I managed to get the VM itself to start, turns out the Virtualisation was disabled in the bios. After enabling that, I was able to boot the VM. I am still having that same network problem though. I did try and change the MAC address again to both the "Ethernet Adapter physical address" and the "Ethernet adapter VBox Host-only Network physical address" it shows in the Command Prompt. Both still has the same issue and I wasn't even able to login to what I assume to be me not being able to connect to the internet on the VM.  It also stopped me from using the internet on the host OS

Comment: In Windows, you need to change public network to private network, if you're at home. In the VM, you've got an invalid MAC address. Leave that field blank. Retry.

Comment: Thank you, that's made it so my internet stays on with the VM open. Ubuntu shows a "?" over what I assume to be the network connection, however, and I still cannot log in. How is it I log in, and is this normal?

Comment: and what is it you mean by leaving the MAC address blank? I can randomise it in vbox but if I leave it blank I cannot save the settings.

Comment: I guess that I don't know how to help you get this working. Sorry.

Comment: I managed to get it working, should I post the answer or delete the post entirely? or neither . . . .

Comment: Post an answer. Be sure to mark it as solved.

Comment: Posted the answer, I know this is probably a stupid question but how do I mark it as solved.

Comment: Click on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being a lot simpler than expected. The network wasn't really the reason the vbox itself couldn't start despite the error, although changing my network settings from public to private in the windows settings did seem to help, but I could still not booth the guest OS. I first needed to enable Virtualisation in my Bios settings for it to boot. After enabling this I was able to boot up the Guest OS. Logging into it required me to go on the website I initially got the image from, and then using the username and password posted on there. The question mark on the login came from me being in Uni halls and needing to first log into the internet first. Now all that has been sorted the guest OS works seamlessly with the internet working also.